# How to use onkeyup in quill editor in nuxt js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

How to use onkeyup, onchange events in quill editor in nuxt js
i have to check the text entered for bad words

```
<quill-editor  id="description" v-model="$v.form.description.$model"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With quill-editor, you can use `@change`

```
<quill-editor :content="text" @change="onTextChange" />

onTextChange(newText) {
  // Do your verification
  this.text = newText;
}
```